# Are "Arc" and "Arch" interchangeable?

Tags: word-difference

I've checked the dictionaries and both words have a common meaning:

**arc** - a shape or structure resembling an arc.

**arch** - a curved symmetrical structure spanning an opening and typically supporting the weight of a bridge, roof, or wall above it.

Can both these words be interchangeable?

- We went through the arc.
- We went through the arch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/arc) definition for arc that you referred to:

> **arc** noun
>
> 1A part of a curve, especially a part of the circumference of a circle:
>      *the point where a tangential line touches the arc of a circle*
>
> 1.1 A shape or structure resembling an arc:
>      *the huge **arc** of the sky*

Note that, although definition 1.1 refers to a **structure**, the word **arc** in the following example (and in all of the other examples quoted) if followed by **of**. **arc** is not an actual structure: it serves only to define the shape of the real structure (the sky).

The definition in the Oxford dictionary would be better written as

> the shape **of** a structure resembling an arc.

Here are the definitions from the Cambridge dictionary: as you can see, there is no (STRUCTURE) meaning for **arc**.

> [arc](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/arc)
>   noun [ C ] (CURVE) the shape of part of a circle, or other curved line.
>
> [arch](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/arch)
>   noun [ C ] (CURVED STRUCTURE) a structure, consisting of a curved top on two supports, that holds the weight of something above it.
>   noun [ C ] (SHAPE) something that has the shape of an arch, often used for decoration:

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/arc

Comment: @SovereignSun I would suggest that usage of arc is rather uncommon and is somewhat metaphorical in comparing the shape of a thing to the shape of a part of a circle - I would encourage you to look at the examples provided on your link. Generally an "arc" will not be understood to be a thing while an "arch" will be.

Comment: So they aren't interchangeable?

Comment: They are definitely not interchangeable.

Comment: does this mean one could say "an arc of an arch"? (whatever that ends up being xd)

Comment: Are the words **archangel, archaeology, archaic, archbishop** somehow connected with the meaning of the word **arch**?

Comment: @SovereignSun: _Archangel_ and _archbishop_ are from Ancient Greek ἄρχω ‎(árkhō): _to lead_. _Archaeology_ and _archaic_ are from Ancient Greek αρχαίος ‎(archaíos): _ancient_. _Arch_ is from Latin arcus : _a bow, arc, arch_. So no, there is no connection.

Comment: @TonyK what about the words "archtop" and "archetype"?

Comment: _Archtop_ (as in "archtop guitar") is indeed derived from _arch_. As for _archetype_, you can look that up yourself on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page).

Comment: There is another definition of Arc i do not see here, The Story arc. It sections off a large/long story into more digestible parts, from the start of a problem/event that drives the story to the conclusion of that part, before starting the next one. Its not used often because there are other natural dividers used at the same time which have other names that we do recognize(like book as in the third book, or season). Its most common use is for some popular Japanese animations (One Piece or Naruto) where there are no seasons, and 100s of episodes following one very long story line.

Comment: Yes @Ryan, there are other definitions of arc, but they are not relevant to an answer for this question. See the Oxford Dictionary link that I provided in my answer for a full list of the definitions, including the one that you refer to.

Answer (score 2):

No. An arch (noun) suggests something that is connected to the ground, like the underside of a bridge or a tunnel. An arc (noun) can be free-floating.

Comment: Do you have a citation for this claim? Is an arched window on the 100th floor "connected to the ground"?

Comment: Well, more broadly, it's in a vertical plane and standing on _something_, even if not the earth itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am a native French speaker, and a translator.
I'd like to make a short terminology comparison.
In English, for architecture, use arch, as in "pointed arch", in all cases. For geometry, use arc, or bow, like in bow-window.

In French, arc's first meaning is "bow"  (cf. archer).
Arche (Fr) is used to describe a large, primarily bow structure, typically in a bridge or a large space. But Arc (Fr) is just generic or for smaller construction elements. Pointed arch e.g. is said Arc Brisé (and not Arche). And for geometry as well it is Arc.

Exception:
On Paris' Champs Élysees, you have the Arc de Triomphe, Rome has the Arc de Titus, which both are rather Arches (Fr) really by their dimensions, but for that kind of monument Arc is the traditionally used terminology. 
London has the Marble Arch.

And finally rainbow is said Arc-en-ciel (litt. a bow in the sky). How nice is that !

I hope this can somehow help & that no one will be upset this little linguistic invasion of mine.

Comment: You should probably add for context that the English words roots are from the French words Arche and Arc